# OpenID Connect : Is it fine to use id_token as access_token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

In one of the application at my work, we are thinking of just using id_token for all the use-cases including authentication and authorization. The solution is being developed from scratch right now. There are currently no consumers of any resources and we can modify the resources to use id_token. I am bit new to the concepts of openid_connect and oauth 2.0. Will there be any issue of just using id_token having all the access details?

Answer (score 16):

ID tokens are meant to be read by the OAuth client. Access tokens are meant to be read by the resource server.

So if your server application is a backend for a frontend (such as JavaScript in browser, mobile app), the OAuth2 client role belongs to that frontend application, so the ID token should stay there and the frontend should not send it to its backend (resource server role). The frontend should send an access token to the backend. Then the backend can use the access token for various purposes:

- Read and validate it directly if it's in JWT form
- Use it for getting user info and scopes from the OAuth2 introspection endpoint if the token is just a random string
- Use the obtained info to allow/deny access to the requested resource (basend on scopes, roles, user or just validity of the token)

Access tokens are also useful for partial access delegation - when a user delegates some of their permissions (scopes) to an application with the OAuth client role. For example if I create an application that asks its users for a read-only access to their GMail, the application can get the access without it being allowed to access any other Google resources of the user.

Access token can be invalidated, ID tokens cannot. So in case of a suspicious activity, OAuth server may invalidate a token preventing its misuse. Resource server should find out about it when requesting the introspection endpoint.

Access tokens have a limited lifetime and an OAuth client must ask for new ones using a refresh token.

In case your application is just a simple server generating its HTML presentation and it has a role of an OAuth2 client (it initializes the auth request), the server can use the received ID token to read info about the authenticated user. Based on that, you can create a server side session to keep the user information and use a browser cookie for further authentication (not using OpenID Connect protocol).

Comment: Thanks Jan for. The case is exactly what mentioned using the example of gmail and other resources. Similar resources exist in our ecosystem being accessed by other apps apart from ours. And the point was can resources be designed to just rely on the id_token; and the fine granular level privileges/access appended to id_token. The other question I am trying to get answered is-what's the advantage of having two tokens? Why can not this be combined in one single token to start with? Are there any fundmtl differences between id_token and access_token apart from the kind of data being stored?

Comment: The ID token was introduced in OpenID Connect for authentication purposes. If you want to delegate access rights, access token was designed exactly for that - users give consent to pass some of their rights to  an application. If you construct your ID token the way it contains scopes (the same way as access tokens), you are creating a new protocol. You should not need to pass ID tokens between applications - they should only prove identity of the user. If one application A calls application B, then A is the caller, not it's user who originally called A.

Comment: Thanks @Ján for the response. "You should not need to pass ID tokens between applications - **_they_** should only prove identity of the user" - When you say they - does application B (resource server) need to prove identity of the user using the access_token? If yes, how would that be done assuming access_token would not have identity information.

Comment: I meant the ID tokens. BTW, you could get a username from access tokens too - using the introspection endpoint. You could also check the OAuth 2.0 Token Exchange RFC, could be interesting for you. And many OAuth2+microservices discussions deal with passing tokens around multiple services.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect many custom/enterprise software scenarios will follow this pattern where you need to proxy or pass through *authentication* from one component of your application to another. You are not dealing with *authorization* in the OAuth2 sense.  The user does not authorize component 1 to make API calls to component 2 on the user's behalf, but rather component 1 and component 2 all look like a single application to the user.

Comment: If you permit an id_token at the resource server, you need to whitelist the 'n' CLIENT audiences that you will allow to call your API, unless you want any application authenticated with your provider to call your API! I'd recommend following the spec or you're going to create security vulnerabilities in the vacuum of solid guidance.

Comment: Suggesting people to break a security protocol, because "it's easier" - sounds like terrible advice. This really shouldn't be the accepted answer imo. "check access rights based on username or roles" how about not using OAuth OpenID Connect at all, if that's how you want to do it? I mean what's next? Are we sending passwords via HTTP, as parameters in a GET request? But let's still call it TLS? “ID Tokens should never be used to obtain direct access to APIs or to make authorization decisions.” https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/id-tokens

Comment: @Heinzlmaen thanks for pointing some incorrect parts, I rewrote the answer. But you could write in a less passionate way - trying to insult others brings no benefit.

Comment: I think part of the confusion comes from understanding why an an id_token is returned at all. The client could just use the access token to verify the identity of the user, so why bother returning an id_token as well?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend following the OIDC spec as designed (i.e. use access_token rather than id_token for resource server authorization) to prevent opening yourself up to security vulnerabilities.

There's a good discussion here about using id_token as an access_token: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2015#issuecomment-147527823

> The spec is designed for the id token to be used in the client and the
> access token to be used at the APIs. I'm sure you can come up with
> some alternative protocol to re-use the id token, but OAuth2 and OIDC
> just didn't evolve that way. I'm sure if they were all designed from
> scratch they'd look different.
>
> As for "is it safe to pass the id token to the backend" -- not sure. I
> really haven't scrutinized the attacks against it or how it could be
> manipulated or fooled. The spec authors do that sort of thing, and
> that's why we tend to stick with their lead since they've spent many
> more hours on it then I have.

Question, why would you use id_token rather than access_token? It's easy to get a real access_token so why go against the spec?

**Update:**

If you do permit an id_token at the resource server (be warned), you need to whitelist each of the client "audiences" that you will allow to call your API, unless you want any application authenticated with your provider to call your API! Again, I'd recommend following the spec or you're going to create security vulnerabilities in the vacuum of solid guidance.

Comment: Thanks @sdoxsee. Actually, the IDP used is a vendor product which does not allow to add custom claims in the access_token. But it does allow customization of id_token. Also, I went  through the link which you shared. I do completely understand the concept behind id_token and access_token. The only confusion is that-are there any significant advantage of having two tokens but separations of concerns.?Also, you mentioned about security vulnerability-I couldn't get more details from the link you shared. But should it not be same as the way access_token is transported. Am I missing something?

Comment: I only mention security vulnerabilities only because it goes against the spec (and all the risks that go with roll-your-own security). I don't see any vulnerabilities with using the id_token for authorization myself but I haven't thought it through. In fact, I remember reading (can't find the link at the moment) that there was some division on the spec team as to whether or not they should use one or two tokens. It could have gone either way but they settled on the two tokens. What vendor OP are you using? surprised it won't support custom claims.

Comment: Thanks @sdoxsee for your response. The one being used in our app is salesforce identity. It's not a full fledged OP.

Comment: I believe this is a narrow interpretation of the spec. Although confusing a client does not have to be an FE, it can be an application (including FE/BE and in some cases even api-based DBs). Access tokens are meant for delegation, users give consent to access their data. However, if you are logging in a user in your application, there is no consent needed, the user can access their own data. That said, many IDPs still think in OAuth terms and force you to use Access Tokens (for example, some don't allow you to refresh ID tokens). Imo Ján Halaša's advice is a proper use of OpenID ID tokens.

Comment: Brecht De Rooms, Ján Halaša's advice is "probably" sound if you've got a simple scenario like he described. The problem I see is "how do you validate the audience claim at your resource server API?" The audience of the id_token is the client requesting the token, not the backend API. If you don't validate audience at your API, then any token (including tokens issued to other clients) will be accepted. To be secure, you'd need to validate 'n' audiences for every client calling your resource server. For that simple scenarios, you should validate the client's audience at the API.

Comment: It depends on how you define client (oauth) or relying party(openId) which is the audience of your ID token. That is the source of different interpretations imo. It is not strictly defined what the Relying Party can be since that is up to you. The spec says "website or application". It is not defined that this application can't be your full stack. As far as I recall, Firebase considers the database even the Relying Party. You are right that it's not common and that's probably due to the fact that before OpenID we had OAuth and API for people with OAuth backgrounds equals resource server.

Comment: For clarity, I do consider your approach correct, as well as the ID token approach as explained by Ján Halaša. However, your answer seems to say that the only way to do it properly is by using access tokens which imo is an OAuth colored interpretation of the OpenID spec. Whether it's ok to use an ID token is depends on what you consider your Relying Party. If you are doing Oauth consent flows  for access to external resources (read, not the API of the app you are developing yourself but an external SaaS) owned by the user, then definitely use access tokens and never ever ID tokens.

Answer (score 1):

All authorization is local.  What that means is that the server with the resource to be shared needs to have the information is needs to make the decision to release the resource, or not. So the question is; does the id_token have sufficient information with the **required level of assurance** to make the authorization or not.  That is the only real question here.